# Как получить размер char без 0?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Не могу сообразить как получить размер массива char после ввода пользователем строчки. Хочется получить фактический размер того что введет пользователь и записать это в переменную

```
char data[50] = { 0 };
cout << "Введите строку: ";
cin >> data;
```

Comment: и что в этом вопросе такого привлекательного? Чем он лучше многих других, которые  были заминусованы?  Странно...

Comment: *получить размер массива char после ввода пользователем строчки* — **размер массива** при записи в него не изменяется...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int len = strlen(data);
```

---

*(Тело сообщения должно содержать не менее 30 символов; вы ввели 23.)*